# Making a really curved container with image inside

Tags: css, image, svg, header, containers

let me start by saying I am not really a developer, I'm a designer but, sometimes developers where I work are really busy or just lazy to really make the designs come to life... So, I put myself in the position of looking for resources, etc. I am asking for help in making a curved container with image inside... an editable container which means, one can change like the direccion of the curve, if it's inside, out, like the images here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFUMi.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwGYh.png

Right now, I pass him the PNG of the image with the curve but as everyone should know, it's just bad for responsive, quality, and so on. I also told him about SVG but he told me that it was not possible I don't know again, if it's true or just laziness. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi -- could you edit your question to include the code you've tried? I'm not sure why the PNG is bad? You might need to use different images, etc. using media-queries to handle different size screens.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to just use pseudo-elements on a container that holds the image (since images can't have psuedo element)

Something like this for the first example: (You can modify height, width, border-radius, and position to suit your needs)

```css
.curved-image {
 position: relative;
 width: 350px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.curved-image:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 160%;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: -10%;
 background-color: green;
}

.curved-image img {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="curved-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

The second example is a bit trickier to do the inverse with this technique, if anyone would like to add to this answer